# Android expandable list view. Scrolling children

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview, children

I'm currently building an application which contains an ExpandableListView. Because I'm using this to display large quantities of data, I would like to allow the user to click on a particular group, display its children, and independently scroll through these children, not the groups. By default, the scroll functionality is tied to the whole list view. I've decided to go with this UI design, due to the user wouldn't want to scroll all the way back up to select another expandable group to view.

I'm not too sure if this is even possible with android. I would post a picture, but my rep is too low :-d.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you tried simulating an `ExpandableListView` by using `LinearLayout`s with `ListView`s underneath? I personally love `ExpandableListView`s, but the only way I can think of accomplishing this task is to have a single child that is a `ListView` and populate the data in there. The only problem is that you will only scroll through one item at a time because of how the `ListView` wraps its content.